# print pandas dataframe left alignment

Tags: pandas

I would like to left align text as below but it not work:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[11,"aaaa"],[1,"a"],[1113,"aa"],[1,"aaaa"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=["x","y"])

df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'left'}).set_table_styles([ dict(selector='th', props=[('text-align', 'left')] ) ])
pd.set_option("colheader_justify", "left")
print(df.to_string(index=False))
#+end_src
```

results:

```
:  x   y   
:   11 aaaa
:    1    a
: 1113   aa
:    1 aaaa
```

what I want is:

```
:  x   y   
: 11   aaaa
: 1    a
: 1113 aa
: 1    aaaa
```

Comment: html styles don't apply to what you get from `to_string`ing a dataframe.

Comment: just cast it as a string first `df.astype(str).to_string..` or better yet, just case that one column.

Answer (score 0):

Try `display(df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'left'}))`:

Results:

|  | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 11 | aaaa |
| 1 | 1 | a |
| 2 | 1113 | aa |
| 3 | 1 | aaaa |

Alternatively, `print(df.to_markdown())` results in

```
|    |    x | y    |
|---:|-----:|:-----|
|  0 |   11 | aaaa |
|  1 |    1 | a    |
|  2 | 1113 | aa   |
|  3 |    1 | aaaa |
```

Comment: Thanks, I got 'display' is not defined error!

Comment: I was running it in colab, so I neglected to mention it since it's build tin there. You need `from IPython.display import display`, and you will need to run `pip install ipython` in bash or cmd if you haven't installed the package

Comment: I am using pure python, but after install ipython, it print out <pandas.io.formats.style.Styler object at 0x7f13fb9b39a0>

Comment: Double check that you have all the parenthesis, you might not be calling the methods